# Linking the index file to the css file

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue with linking my html to the external CSS using the following folder structure.

```
project
|  index
|  |  index.html
|  css
   |  style.css
```

In this case, how would i link the `index.html` to the `style.css`?

Answer (score 3):

The  tag

> is an HTML tag which is not only intended to link style sheets,
> but which can also refer to other HTML pages on the site, linked by a
> hierarchy. For example, it is possible to indicate the next page in a
> series of documents, or the parent page, to go up one level in the
> navigation. It can also be used to indicate an external resource such
> as an RSS or Atom feed, or a favicon . In any case, an element
> has at least two attributes: rel(type of relationship) and
> href(linked resource).
>
> Here is a summary of the specific attributes, in the case of use with
> a style sheet:
>
> rel="stylesheet", to indicate that the relation linking the HTML document to this file is that of a style sheet
> type="text/css", to indicate its MIME type,
> eventually media="le type de média destination"to exploit it according to one consultation medium or the other ( screen, print...)
> or even attribute titlein the case of persistent and alternate style sheets.

Example :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="habillage.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="texte.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="impression.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

The @import rule

> @importis a CSS2 property that must be followed by the URL of a file
> that will contain styles to apply in addition to the current style
> sheet. You can use @import:
>
> between the tags and in the section an HTML
> page;   at the beginning of a CSS file, to include one or more other
> style sheets;
>
> This second possibility is interesting because it allows you to create
> more scalable style sheets (a single file is linked from the HTML
> page, and the import of style sheets is managed directly from this
> root CSS file). Problem: this operation can slightly slow down the
> loading of styles and therefore of the page, and it is not recommended
> in a process of optimizing client performance.

Example :

```
<style type="text/css">
  @import url(/styles/habillage.css);
  @import url(/styles/texte.css);
</style>
```

You can optionally add a list of media. But beware, Internet Explorer 6-7 does not understand this syntax, and will not import the corresponding style sheet at all! (Internet Explorer 8+ fixes this problem).

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
  @import url(impression.css);
</style>
```

This property also allows style sheets to be imported into other style sheets. This offers possibilities to create dynamic style sheets without having to copy the same code several times.